# How to copy data from sheet1 of workbook1 to sheet 2 of Workbook2?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy Data from `Sheet1` of `Workbook1` to `Sheet2` of `Workbook2`. I need to copy data of sheet 1 from `A1` to `AE`(LastRow) and paste the whole copied data to `Q1` of `Sheet2` of `Workbook2`.

Here is my code:

```
Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\Excel\Workbook1.xlsx")

     For Each oSheet In wbkA.Sheets

        If oSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
           Set NewWorksheetA = wbkA.Worksheets(oSheet.Name)
        End If

    Next oSheet
Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\Excel\Workbook2.xlsx")

     For Each oSheet In wbkB.Sheets

        If oSheet.Name = "Sheet2" Then
           Set NewWorksheetB = wbkB.Worksheets(oSheet.Name)
        End If

    Next oSheet
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' for Loop for row and Column Starts here to compare the data
If Not NewWorksheetA Is Nothing Then

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' Getting Last Column index from current Worbook to Write the UpdateStatus
LastRow = NewWorksheetA.Cells(NewWorksheetA.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox "Last Row Number:" & LastRow
LastColumn = NewWorksheetA.Cells(8, NewWorksheetA.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'MsgBox "Last Column Number:" & LastColumn

Workbooks("D:\Excel\Workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AE" & LastRow).Copy _
Workbooks("D:\Excel\Workbook2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Q1")

End If
```

I am getting the below error

> ```
> Run Time Error 9:
>
> Subscript out of range.
> ```

I would like to use the variable used for Workbook and sheet name

Comment: On which line of your code does the error occur?

Comment: What is `NewWorksheetA` you overwrite it each time.  Also the copy and paste operation is within workbook1 only

Comment: The 2nd loop i on wbkA also, instead of wbkB

Comment: @Variatus I am getting error at last two lines

Comment: Are you sure workbook 2 has a sheet 2?

Comment: @Warcupine: Yes the workbook 2 has sheet 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
Workbooks("D:\Excel\Workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AE" & LastRow).Copy _
Workbooks("D:\Excel\Workbook2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Q1")
```

with this:

```
NewWorksheetA.Range("A1:AE" & LastRow).Copy
NewWorksheetB.Range("Q1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Hope my answer helps. :)